What does the icon with 3 horizontal yellow lines over a folder mean?
In IntelliJ IDEA, I've noticed that some of my folders in the project view have an icon with three horizontal yellow lines overlaying them. The rest of the folders have different icons, and I'm curious about the significance of this particular icon.
I would like to understand what the icon with the three horizontal yellow lines represents in IntelliJ IDEA. Does it indicate a specific type of folder or have any special meaning in terms of project structure or configuration? Additionally, how does IntelliJ IDEA determine when to display this icon over a folder?
Any insights or explanations regarding this IntelliJ IDEA icon would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!


This typically indicates a folder with resources or test resources.
You can see it in the documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html (scroll a little bit down.
